# Is it possible to install multiple android applications in one APK file?

Tags: android

Say I have multiple .apk files. Is it possible to combine all these into one .apk file for the convenience of the end user?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/market/publishing/multiple-apks.html
I hope this is going to make clean it to you!

Comment: @Karoly - that does not seem particularly relevant.

Answer (score 5):

You can compile multiple activities into the same apk, and have them show up separately in the home screen launcher.  This would make them appear separate to the user, but they'd still formally be part of the same android "application" - they would run under the same user ID and so have access to each other's data, and could only be uninstalled as a group.

Comment: can you help me with this, with some kind of example or tutorial.

Comment: @VenomVendor see this example: http://www.chainfire.eu/articles/133/_TUT_Supporting_multiple_icons_in_your_app/

Answer (score 0):

You have to include either package or activities into the single project and these activities must be connected with each other in some way as there would be only one main activity defined in manifest file. So, it must be in the sequence in which you want to show. That's it and otherwise i don't think it gets happen through any other way ........... :)

Comment: No, you don't need one main activity in an .apk; you can have as many as you want (or none at all).  See Google Maps, for example, which I believe now has 4.  If these are going to fully operate as separate apps, you *do* probably need to provide separate android:taskAffinity names for them so they don't get mixed together.

Comment: I mean you need to start with single activity otherwise how you will recongnize from which to start.

Comment: Simply give the various launcher Activities descriptive names and distinctive icons.  The user picks what they want, just like they do with things provided by distinct APK's.