# How to deploy both applications using 1 apk file?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to install multiple android applications in one APK file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4426015/is-it-possible-to-install-multiple-android-applications-in-one-apk-file)

Actually I have 2 applications
1. Main application (contains many activities)
2. Additional application (contains one widjet)

My goal is to avoid 2 apk files and deploy 2 applications using only one apk file.
Please suggest how to implement this

Comment: That's pretty well documented. What did you find out with your research and what exactly didn't work?

Comment: If the user has to install both apps in any case, then why not have them in one?

Answer (score 1):

What you want is not supported. Put them in a single application. You do not need separate applications here, and there is but one application per APK file.