# How to run multiple apps on the same screen in Android?

Tags: android, customization

I want to customize Android source code so that it can run multiple applications on same Screen. Is that possible?

You can check out my work so far at this [link](http://www.themobileindian.com/news/940_View-multiple-apps-on-one-Android-screen)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using virtual machines but is the worst option (talking in memory terms).

Comment: It should be like 50% of screen covered by one app, and rest of 50% by another app, I don't think so that it is possible with VM. It would be just another scenario with VM.

Answer (score 0):

You can't run multiple applications on the same screen but you can run multiple screens of a single application on the same screen and on same time.....for more information see this...

[Is it possible to install multiple android applications in one APK file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4426015/is-it-possible-to-install-multiple-android-applications-in-one-apk-file)

Comment: I have already gone through this link, But here I want to  customize Android Source Code.